# HTTP GET of GWT cache file returns truncated file

Tags: gwt, caching, truncate

I've developed a GWT application that is working well for 99% of my customers... however, I've recently bumped into a couple of customers who were having troubles in running the App.

After further investigation I've found out that one of the .cache files are getting corrupted while downloaded and some parts of the file get truncated... ?!

I was not able to detect the root cause for this weird failure... here are all my findings + facts I'm aware of:

- problem is occurring in both IE and Chrome and thus, browser independent.
- I have noticed that the customer was having some malware issues on his machine which causes google search results to lead (once clicked over) to some ab?? something website (this was only occurring on Chrome actually)
- Running fiddler on the machine shows that the file gets fully downloaded with HTTP response of 200 == OK
- The truncated bits of code (roughly about 10 javascript functions in the middle of the file) were replaced with a string <!-ESFSECEV-TY3003-------
  with many more dashes and at the end ----> ....searching for this weird term yielded nothing in google...

any help on this one would be very much appreciated,

thanks a lot,

GBa.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a firewall or network proxy issue.

I think I heard of antivirus software munging up downloaded javascript to 'protect' the users.

Comment: Yeah, I should have posted as a comment and not an answer. I meant to communicate: 'Is there a common firewall, proxy, or antivirus on the affected user's computers?' Try disabling/uninstalling and see if that helps. Sorry I don't have a better answer.